# erro de instalação de recursos do vue no ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vue.js

observem os comandos abaixo;

```
root@wlady-VirtualBox:/home/wlady/Documentos/music-db/frondend# yarn add vuex vuex-router-sync vue-router axios animate.css google-material-color material-design-icons laravel-echo pusher-js
yarn add v1.1.0
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning "ajv-keywords@1.5.1" has unmet peer dependency "ajv@>=4.10.0".
error Could not write file "/home/wlady/Documentos/music-db/frondend/yarn-error.log": "ENOSPC: no space left on device, open '/home/wlady/Documentos/music-db/frondend/yarn-error.log'"
error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOSPC: no space left on device, copyfile '/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v1/npm-material-design-icons-3.0.1-9a71c48747218ebca51e51a66da682038cdcb7bf/places/ios/ic_pool_white_18pt.imageset/ic_pool_white_18pt.png' -> '/home/wlady/Documentos/music-db/frondend/node_modules/material-design-icons/places/ios/ic_pool_white_18pt.imageset/ic_pool_white_18pt.png'".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
root@wlady-VirtualBox:/home/wlady/Documentos/music-db/frondend#
```

Porque será que gerou erro?
E como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja o erro:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOSPC: no space left on device,
```

É falta de espaço em disco.